# Nullable datetime compiler limitation

Tags: asp.net, datetime, null, conditional-statements

I take Date info from Sql query and if it exists, assign it to a variable, if not - leave date_1 empty. Compiler tries to predict that date_1 may be null and prevents using it, but it doesn't see that I check if it is null before using it. What's wrong with it?

1st situation - I use **bool** flag to indicate that date is not null

```
DateTime date_1;
bool date_1_exists = false;

if (!reader1.IsDBNull(reader1.GetOrdinal("date_1")))
{
    date_1_exists = true;
    date_1 = Convert.ToDateTime(reader1["date_1"]);
}
if (date_1_exists == true)
{
    label1.Text = "date_1: " + date_1.ToString(); // Compiler marks date_1 as error
    label2.Text = "date_2: " + (date_1.AddYears(1)).ToString() + ".";
}
```

2nd situation - I use **nullable datetime**

```
DateTime? date_1;

if (!reader1.IsDBNull(reader1.GetOrdinal("date_1")))
    date_1 = Convert.ToDateTime(reader1["date_1"]);
else
    date_1 = null;

if (date_1.HasValue)
{
    label1.Text = "date_1: " + date_1.ToString(); 
    label2.Text = "date_2: " + (date_1.AddYears(1)).ToString() + "."; // Compiler marks AddYears as error
}
```

How can I use a DateTime variable that can be null, but if it is not null, it should be used in further calculations.

Comment: Please show the exact compiler error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the **2nt situation** you just need to tell him that is not null

so change this code

```
(date_1.AddYears(1)).ToString()
```

to this

```
(((DateTime)date_1).AddYears(1)).ToString()
```

**For the 1st case** the compiler recognize that you try to "render" a value (DateTime) that probably did not have any value, so if you go with the first DateTime make sure that all paths on your program logic, place a value to `date_1`, or define the `date_1` with a default start value, eg

`DateTime date_1 = default(DateTime);`

So the first code can be

```
DateTime date_1 = default(DateTime);

if (!reader1.IsDBNull(reader1.GetOrdinal("date_1")))
{
    date_1 = Convert.ToDateTime(reader1["date_1"]);

    label1.Text = "date_1: " + date_1.ToString();
    label2.Text = "date_2: " + (date_1.AddYears(1)).ToString() + ".";

}
```

or to be more close to your code

```
DateTime date_1 = default(DateTime);

if (!reader1.IsDBNull(reader1.GetOrdinal("date_1")))
{
    date_1 = Convert.ToDateTime(reader1["date_1"]);
}

if (date_1 != default(DateTime))
{
    label1.Text = "date_1: " + date_1.ToString();
    label2.Text = "date_2: " + (date_1.AddYears(1)).ToString() + ".";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Presumably this is happening inside a method as local variables are not automatically initialized (unlike member variables). As such, you're probably getting a `Use of unassigned local variable` compiler error. You could assign `date_1` the default value and check for that for future calculations.

```
DateTime date_1 = default(DateTime);

//when checking
if(date_1 != default(DateTime))
{
    label1.Text = "date_1: " + date_1.ToString(); 
    label2.Text = "date_2: " + (date_1.AddYears(1)).ToString() + ".";
}
```

Comment: `DateTime` is a value type, not a reference type (it's a struct). It can never be null unless you use the nullable version as per your second example :)

Answer (score 0):

(a bit late, but...) A *Nullable* DateTime is primarily a [Nullable struct](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.nullable-1) and just knows about the methods of that, such as `.ToString()` and `.GetValueOrDefault()`.

When you have tested that `date_1` has a value, then you can safely use the `.Value` property. This returns a real (non-nullable) `DateTime` and thus has all those methods.

So:

```
label2.Text = "date_2: " + date_1.Value.AddYears(1).ToString() + ".";
```